# How to set the height of FormTextField when there is prefixIcon present

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using the following code to generate a `TextFormField` which I can change the height by changing the vertical padding of the text field.

```
final hotelSearchField = TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  focusNode: _hotelSearchFocus,
  controller: _hotelSearchController,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
  onFieldSubmitted: (term) {},
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7.0, horizontal: 20),
    hintText: "Search",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
  ),
);
```

But when I add `prefixIcon` to the `TextFormField` decoration, I can't change the height of the `TextFormField` by changing the vertical padding.

```
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7.0, horizontal: 20),
    hintText: "Search",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 20.0),
  )
```

I tried reducing Icon size. But it only changes the size of the Icon, padding is same.

Without focus:

[image: without focus]

With focus:

[image: with focus]

I want only the height reduced.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prefixIcon` will sure for leave some padding in `TextFormField` instead of that you can use the below described way where you can be able to adjust the height, width and padding of icon as well `TextFormField`. In the below example we take the `Container` and `Row` and divide it with the help of `flex` property of `Expanded` widget. After that we can change the height and width of icon with the help of any child widget such as `Padding` or `SizedBox`, etc., Also by using below way, we can be able to change the height and width of `TextFormField` with padding.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: NumericComboLineBarChart(),
    );
  }
}

class NumericComboLineBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MY APP'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
//              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
                       child: Icon(
                         Icons.search,
                         size: 10.0,
                       ),)
                    ),
                    flex: 1,
                  ),

                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (term) {},
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7.0, horizontal: 0),
                        hintText: "Search",
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                    flex: 9,
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)